# opening a large pdf files on web

Tags: pdf, web

I have a 27MB pdf file which is hosted in web. When I try to open it, it takes times to open it. So Is there any way where I can view this large pdf file a bit fast. I guess there are some settings where we can view the pages of the file once after some pages are downloaded.
ANy solution to this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do to your PDF is to make them "web optimized". The technically more correct term is to make them "linearized":

- Acrobat + Distiller and a lot of other tools can do that.
- Ghostscript also ships an additional PostScript-written helper utility named `pdfopt.ps` which can do this. Simply run:
   `gs -q -dNODISPLAY -P- -dSAFER -dDELAYSAFER -- /path/to/pdfopt.ps input.pdf optimized.pdf`, or if you are on Windows:
   `gswin32.exe -q -dNODISPLAY -P- -dSAFER -dDELAYSAFER -- c:/path/to/pdfopt.ps input.pdf optimized.pdf`

Normally `pdfopt.ps` should be installed together with your Ghostscript in the installation path's `lib/` subdirectory. If not, you can [download pdfopt.ps](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=blob_plain;f=gs/lib/pdfopt.ps;hb=HEAD) from the Ghostscript Git repository.

Linearization re-organizes the PDF internally, so that (a copy of) its internal ToC of PDF objects (in technical terms: its "*xref* table") is put close to the beginning of the file (instead of its end), plus some more changes.

That way, a spec-conforming PDF reader will be able to start rendering the first page before the rest of the file has been loaded. It will even be possible to jump to the last page and view it before the middle pages are downloaded, if you are accessing the PDF over the web using HTTP-based protocols. But then, the web server is required to support the HTTP  "byte range" requests (otherwise this will not work even for linearized PDFs).

You can read some more details about PDF linearizations in the official PDF-1.7 ISO standard spec, [available on the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

- in its (normative) Annex F, *"Linearized PDF"*, starting on page 683, and
- in its (informative) Annex G, *"Linearized PDF Access Strategies"*, starting on page 703.

An example of a linearized PDF [can be found here](http://acrobatineducation.com/files/Employability_Skills_Manual_2009_OPT.pdf)

---

### Update (2013-2-15)

Since release 9.07 of Ghostscript, linearized ("web optimized") PDF output can be generated directly (without the 2-step approach outlined above) by adding the following switch to the commandline:

```
-dFastWebView=true
```

Since the `pdfopt.ps` file is now redundant, it has been removed from the current Ghostscript source repository.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what reader/plugins display such PDFs while being loaded?

Comment: Acrobat (Reader) itself certainly does... (But see also this link for some complaints about its Version X browser plugin not working for *all* major browsers: http://acrobatusers.com/forum/general-acrobat-topics/acrobat-x-fast-web-view-not-working-some-browsers )

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a pdf library like [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/) to render the page images from the PDF on the server side, and then (through AJAX) present the images to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible workaround would be:

If the PDF doesn't usually change you can set an `cache expiry` for the resource (set in the `response`), so that when clients opens the pdf/view the resource is cached in their browser, will reduce load time on their second visit (depending on how long it expires of course)

Another option, if it is possible, try to load the pdf file `asynchronously`. That is load the other contents of your web page first, then your pdf will be loaded after.

Or you can do a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Kurt's comment. I assembled this command line and it seemed to do the trick for generating an optimized PDF file:

```
gs -q -P- -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView -sOutputFile=optimized.pdf input.pdf
```

You can check the output with `pdfinfo optimized.pdf` where you should see `Optimized:      yes` in the output

Answer (score -1):

Another great approach is you can use google docs viewer.

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=yoururl&embedded=true
```

This automatically preload's the initial pages without any additional setup, so you don't have to wait for the entire pdf to load.